# Catching when a user denies a full-screen toggle in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullscreen

Is there a way to find out when a user clicks on the `Toggle Full Screen` button and then clicks `Deny` in the browser popup? (Or listen to the event when the browser forcefully sends back my app to window mode from full screen?)

Currently when I click `Deny` in the browser pop-up after setting the app to Full Screen, it gets sent back to window mode, but the app variables/classes stay set to FullScreen mode, until I manually click the button again.

My current code to toggle fullscreen is:

```
if ($scope.fullScreen === true && !document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {

    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }

} else {

    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
        document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you cannot get such info directly, you have to query the window mode either on window resize or any other relevant events.